# Is it possible to show existence of geodesics via a minimization argument?

Tags: differential-geometry

Usually existence of geodesics is proven by applying ODE existence/uniqueness to the geodesic equations. But subsequent discussion of geodesics usually talks of the relation between geodesics and length minimization. There it is shown that (local) minimizers of length must be geodesics.

Can we establish existence of minimizers of the length/energy functionals via a calculus of variations argument? To my knowledge, this would require (a) showing the Lagrangian is lower semicontinuous, and (b) showing that the space of paths is compact in a suitable topology. However, I don't know if this is possible in the Riemannian case. (In the Lorentzian case, one can do so if you restrict to causal curves, though I haven't read much about the specific topology used there.)

Comment: Yes, this can be done in a straightforward way. The key trick is to minimize the energy functional $\int_0^1 |c'(t)|^2\,dt$, $c: [0,1]\rightarrow M$, instead of the length of the curve, where $c(0) = p$ and $c(1) = q$. Any energy minimizing sequence can be shown to have a subsequence that converges uniformly to a continuous curve. By the lower semicontinuity of the $L^2$ norm of $c'$, the limiting curve has finite energy. It therefore is energy-minimizing, which implies that it is a constant speed geodesic.

Comment: I believe that is how it is described in Milnor's Morse Theory.

Comment: @Deane does the limit necessarily have to be differentiable, though? Is this something about the topology used, or about the fact that the sequence is minimzing?

Comment: @Chris, there are technical details, but the idea is the following: Since the limiting curve is energy-minimizing, it is a weak solution to the Euler-Lagrange equations, which in local coordinates is $$ \ddot{c}^i + \Gamma^i_{jk}\dot{c}^j\dot{c}^k = 0. $$ Since $\dot{c}$ is $L^2$, the second term is $L^1$, which in turn implies that $\ddot{c}$ is in $L^1$. That implies that $\dot{c}$ is continuous and therefore $c$ is $C^1$. If $\Gamma$ is smooth, you can repeat this argument indefinitely and conclude that $c$ is smooth.